# Golang time.Parse() get 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Tags: go

This is my code:

```
t, _ := time.Parse("12/1/2015 12:00:00", "12/8/2015 12:00:00")
fmt.Println(t)
```

This is the result: `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`

How to get correct the date string?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the proper format string. Duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the reference timestamp `2006-01-02 15:04:05` for the layout parameter ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vl3i4PL-6m)):

```
t, _ := time.Parse("1/2/2006 15:04:05", "12/8/2015 12:00:00")
```

Comment: If this (or any other) answer solved your problem, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141962). Thanks!